# PostgreSQL trigger copy record to another table with different columns order

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I have a trigger that before every update on hundreds of tables it inserts into a table with the same name and the _hv suffix a copy of the record being updated to maintain a kind of historical updates.

So when there is an update in my_example table. The table my_example_hv that has the same fields in the beginning of the table and some extra fields in the end (update timestamps, update user, etc). Using this line it works perfectly:

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO '|| TG_RELNAME ||'_hv SELECT  ($1).*' USING NEW;
```

Ok the problem comes when I need to insert a new field to the main table.
I can add the new field too to the _hv table but I can't reorder the fields in my postgresql version (8.4). I know it's obsolete but I can't upgrade it right now because I have some old software that needs that version of postgresql.

So what would be the code to insert the record to th _hv table having some field now in different order but with the same column names?

Comment: Erm, why not just list the column names?

Comment: because I need a trigger that works for the hundreds of tables I've got, so I can avoid having to create hundreds of triggers

Comment: Listing the column names is probably the only way you're going to get this to work. I'd query metadata to generate column lists or even entire triggers.

Comment: If `hstore(NEW.*)`  works with 8.4, you might use that to reconstruct a dynamic insert with column names in any order as hstore keys, and column values as corresponding hstore values.

Comment: @Daniel Vérité could ypu please write an answer so I can accept it? Do I have to hstore(NEW.*) to convert it in key=>value pairs but how do I insert those records in a new table in the correct order?

Comment: I am in postgresql 8.4 and i can't see a clear solution